# How to NOT create a link in a tweet

Tags: twitter

Whenever I type something resembling a URL (for example "asp.net") at twitter.com, it automatically converts it into a real link. Is there a way to 'escape' this conversion if I want it to remain plain text?

Comment: is there a reason? Usually things like superuser-dot-com are not translated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only practical way I've found is to munge the URL in some way. Enclosing in single-quotes, double-quotes, parentheses, brackets, braces, backticks, etc., has no effect.

The classic way is to "escape" the dot character: `asp[dot]net`.

Adding a couple of extra spaces *around* the dot would also do the trick: `asp . net`.

If you can manage to insert a zero-length character (such as U+200B) in the string, that should do the trick as well. (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> seems to work on Windows.)

The only other way I can see to make this happen is to use a third-party Twitter client. Then again, the API may convert the URL-like strings to URLs on the server side anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Go to this site: http://www.labnol.org/internet/twitter-auto-converts-links/20771/ and type your "URL resembling" text in the textbox. It will output the same text which does not create a hyperlink in a tweet. It can also be used to remove hyperlinks from @mentions and #hashtags

More explanation is in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nmq908lqCmk

Comment: What text box??